# Xamarin.Android error "PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, mono

I got this error when i changed my project folder in xamarin.android.

- Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
  Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
  Could not load assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0,
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't
  exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
  'PresentationFramework.dll' at
  Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
  reference, ReaderParameters parameters) at
  Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
  reference) at
  Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
  resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
  Boolean topLevel) at
  Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
  resolver) Project.Novo

Can you help-me? ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it, i just add reference from "Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\'VERSION\'Nome da DLL'".